# Extract 6 letters containing atleast a lowercase alphabet and atleast one uppercase alphabet and atleast one number?

Tags: python, regex

Consider the string :

```
text = "aaAA23 aAAA32 32AeeeB  fjdSkjj839jl2lkjj"
pat = ?
result = re.findall(pat, text)
```

I am looking for a pattern, which would give the following result :

```
["aaAA23", "aAAA32", "32Aeee", "dSkjj8"]
```

I am doing it in a naive way:

```
pat = "[a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+|[A-Z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+|[a-z]+[0-9]+[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+[0-9]+[a-z]+|[0-9]+[a-z]+[A-Z]+|[0-9]+[A-Z]+[a-z]+"
```

which is not working, as it yields:

```
["aaAA23", "aAAA32", "32Aeee", "Skjj839"]
```

How to do it?

Comment: do they have to be next to each other? Or just randomly from the string?

Comment: But you don't care about `'2AeeeB'`, `'Skjj83'`, etc.? That is, you're only looking for the *first* substring meeting your requirements from every string separated by word separators in your text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use lookaheads that match each required character type.

```
pat = r'(?=.{0,5}[a-z])(?=.{0,5}[A-Z])(?=.{0,5}\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{6}'
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/TMtw6S/1)